# Pulling dockerhub image in github action failing

Tags: node.js, yaml, github-actions, dockerhub, docker-pull

I am trying to host a node application using aws ec2 instance. and I am using Docker hub so that i can use GitHub to push the changes. I have created a free tier account in Docker hub and created a repository. and created a cicd.yml file inside .github/workflows. the yml file looks like this

```
name: Deploy Node Application

on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - mern-ec2-docker

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Source
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Login to docker hub
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build Docker Image
        run: docker build -t ziendocker/zien-backend  .
      - name: Publish Image to docker hub
        run: docker push ziendocker/zien-backend:latest 
 
  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: self-hosted 
    steps:
      - name: Pull image from docker hub
        run: docker pull ziendocker/zien-backend 
      - name: Delete old container
        run: docker rm -f nodejs-app-container  
      - name: Run Docker Container
        run: docker run -d -p 4000:4000 --name nodejs-app-container -e MONGO_PASSWORD='${{ secrets.MONGO_PASSWORD }}' ziendocker/zien-backend
```

The Dockerfile created along looks like this

```
FROM node:alpine3.18
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npm","run","start"]
```

the build job runs successfully, login successfully  and the image has been pushed to the Docker hub. But when running the job deploy in Pull image from docker hub results an in an error

> Run docker pull ziendocker/zien-backend

> docker pull ziendocker/zien-backend
> shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
> Using default tag: latest
> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ziendocker/zien-backend, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

since the image is already published to the  docker hub the access credentials are correct.where did i go wrong?

i tried `docker pull ziendocker/zien-backend:latest` resulted in same error .changed the initial login to

```
- name: Login to Docker Hub
  uses: docker/login-action@v3
  with:
    username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
```

it resulted in

```
Run docker/login-action@v3
  with:
    password: ***
    ecr: auto
    logout: true
Error: Username and password required
```

tried a new access token from docker. same error on deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

Both approaches should work, but you are using two different secret variable names (`DOCKER_USERNAME` vs `DOCKERHUB_USERNAME`). Which one is correct, and are you sure they are configured to `secrets` and not `variables`?

```
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
```

```
    username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
```

Anyway, the real problem is here:

```
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Source
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Login to docker hub
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
     ...
  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Pull image from docker hub
        run: docker pull ziendocker/zien-backend
    ...
```

You have two different jobs, the first one does the pushing and the other one the pulling. First of all, the login does not persist between jobs. Neither does the runner, each job spins up a fresh one. And that does not apply here anyway since your runners are anyway configured as different.

It's the same if you logged in on your desktop first and expected the pull to work on your brand new laptop next.

### Solution

So, what you need to do is to just add the login also to the second job:

```
    steps:
      - name: Login to docker hub
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Pull image from docker hub
        run: docker pull ziendocker/zien-backend 
      ...
```

and it should work just by doing that.

Comment: thank you for the elaborated clarification. that worked. I was following a YouTube video tutorial ,but he didn't included it. that's why I got it wrong.